# In Wordpress Admin Panel, In column title bar I want to rename categories with word "Groups"without using plugins. How do I do it?

Tags: php, wordpress

Please visit below URL for Screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add filter with code bellow to search for the categories columns and replace them with your custom text (Groups). Code goes into functions.php file of your theme or your child theme.

```
 add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'rename_to_groups' );

function rename_to_groups( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['categories'] = 'Groups';
    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: In wordpress main directory ,in that in which folder i do edit WP-content folder ?

Comment: /wp-content/themes/your active theme/functions.php and paste it to the bottom of the php file and save it.

Comment: yes sir i had done but not get result i want to do on admin dashboard under all post tab.

Comment: @tanmaykshirsagar I have updated my answer with a working solution. Try now.

Comment: @tanmaykshirsagar Did it work? If yes please set the answer as right answer. Thank you.